# Skin URL in controller

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, skin

I want to get skin URL in Magento Controller. I tried this

> Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);

but it returns

```
http://magento_root/skin/
```

How can I get the URL like the one give below.

```
http://magento_root/skin/frontend/rwd/default
```

I need this because I want to set an image path in API response in controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon you should try:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getSkinBaseUrl();
```

Comment: Exactly what i want. Thanks @Raphael , It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/your-image.jpg');
```